# Scala Spark Cassandra Table update

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Scala Version: 2.11 Spark : 2.2

Is it possible to write a Scala script or Spark Script to update data from one cassandra Table to Other. I am fairly new to these worlds. What I am looking for is Table B must be updated when ever Table A is updated. Table B has data which is subset of Table A.

Example

```
Table A - Sno , Name, Gender, Address, Rank. 
Table B - Sno, Name, Rank.
```

Table A is updated as and when batch job is run using Spark. Now how do I make changes happened in Table A to reflect on Table B ?

Comment: Do you really need a separate table? Aren't you needlessly duplicating data that way?

Comment: yes we are. We are not worried about duplicating Data. We need Table B to run the queries faster.

Comment: Why don't you try Materialized views? Cassandra already has this kind of solution and this is materialized views. If you build that with a script will be really slow to check this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update. But our data in Table A is so big it has bore than 8-9 billion records with 350 columns of Data. So we were planning to have subtables. Do you still suggest Materialized Views instead of Table B?